# Adding a layer to a loaded model in Tensorflow Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have a Keras model, with pre-trained weights stored in .hdf5 and with the model architecture stored in a .json file. The architecture file does not include the softmax layer. When I tried to load the model in to Tensorflow Keras, there was an error saying

> ValueError: You are trying to load a weight file containing 5 layers into a model with 4 layers.

It makes sense because the weights file include the softmax layer whereas the architecture doesn't.

I then tried to load the architecture and then add a softmax layer to it before loading the weights.

```
new_model = keras.models.model_from_json(json)
res = Activation('softmax')(new_model.output)
res = Model(inputs=new_model.input, outputs=res)
res.load_weights('weights.hdf5')
```

But it would not work, and the same error message appears.

Is there a way to add a layer to the loaded architecture before loading weights?

I am using Tensorflow 2.5.0.

Comment: Maybe you are mixing keras and tensorflow.keras libraries. Check if you are using everywhere tensorflow.keras, not keras.

Comment: @Kaveh Yes, I made sure to explicitly specify the tensorflow.keras when doing the predictions.